# Hooking onto entering and leaving window in i3

Tags: i3

Is it possible to hook onto the events of entering and leaving a window in i3?  I want to use this to make my winkey hyper in Emacs and super outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under X11 you could use `xprop` to listen for all window activation events and then execute some logic that depends on window class name.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

xprop -spy -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | grep --line-buffered -o '0[xX][a-zA-Z0-9]\{7\}' |
while read -r id; do
    class="$(xprop -id $id WM_CLASS)"
    if [ -n "$class" ]; then
        echo "Active window class is: $class"
    fi
done
```